# Submit form with AJAX and method POST

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a difficulty in implementing an MVC system.
I have a simple comment system, which makes the record when sent via POST or via AJAX.

**a)** Should I separate the 2 controllers in Comment_Ajax and Comment_Post
**b)** or should I just keep a controller and and check the sent method (is_ajax()) to perform the necessary actions.

Form method 'Post' redirects to the page of the post and form method 'Ajax' only makes a reload in the comments.

Comment: How is any of this related to a language-independent architectural pattern?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo MVC framework which provides this solution.

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski why would you recommend that singleton-driven and procedural disaster to anyone?

Comment: @tereško, can you recommend some reading?

Comment: @tereško why you say it's a disaster?

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski because I looked at the code. It should have never been published.

Comment: @PapaCharlie , not from top of my head. The fact, that page was accessed using XHR, should have **no impact** on how it is processed and how response is rendered. The response that you get (whether HTML or JSON) should depend on the parameters that you passed. Something along the lines of `/form/send` versus `/form/send.json`.

Comment: @tereško Can you give some examples? I think your opinion is wired.

Comment: tells you to hold a controller and pass as parameter the type of response: JSON or HTML ... "Dear controller, save these data and the response in JSON!" Is this it?

Comment: Controllers are not responsible for producing a response. Instead that value would indicate that either a simple or json view has to be initialized. The view itself is responsible for deciding which templates to choose and what sort of information to gather from model layer. As I said before: you question has nothing to do with MVC. It's actually about URL routing.

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski if you want you framework to be reviewed, there is a special stackexchange site for it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Or you can go to [php chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and ask people to review it. Do not spam it in random comments.

Comment: I faked the dialogue was very simple, just to illustrate. the controller receives the parameters (data form and the type of response that will represent the view). then with ajax method i have a JSON response, to POST method and I will have a subsequent redirect. i think i understand the question

Comment: You can codeigniter it is php mvc framework it is very much easy to use and well documented http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

Comment: @souvickcse , FYI, EllisLab has stopped maintaining codeigniter. It also is universally regarded as one of two worst framework in php (along with cakephp). You should should not recommend it for newbies. It's filled with bad practices and artifacts from PHP4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with version b, keeping related methods together. Keep DRY: Don´t Repeat Yourself.

What you are doing are 2 actions (methods/functions) of one controller, which is pefectly valid MVC. Usually a controller has one action "render" (display page if no parameters are present), and can have multiple actions like save, update, submit, render_ajax etc.

Comment: -1: no, controllers are not responsible for rendering stuff. Neither are they responsible for saving and updating persistence.

Comment: @tereško: controller are responsible to accept user-input. So if the user hits "save", he calls the save-method of the controller, that loads the model and makes it save to the persistence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good option to create more controllers.

I didn't understand your statement "Form method 'Post' redirects to the page of the post and form method 'Ajax' only makes a reload in the comments".

Generally we can comment to a post if we are in corresponding post page, again you are saying 'post' will redirect to post page.

Based on Client requirement we will go for 'reload the page' or 'just updating commnets section with AJAX'.

And moreover, what ever is the process you follow, Just write  one method like saveComment(); and call this method, through form action if it is Post, or mention this method in AJAX call.